# Is there a setSource parameter that I can use for a button/image click event in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Is there such a thing as setSource for a layer, as there is in OpenLayers 3, in Leaflet? Or something equivalent? I can't find it in the API documentation.

**UPDATE WITH MORE INFORMATION**

I am trying to add a click event for an image, so that when I click an external image it changes the source of the tile layer (L.tilelayer.deepzoom). It would be awesome if I could get it to change the layer source of 4 layers to different paths.

**For Example:**

```
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path1)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path2)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path3)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path4)
```

[ Button Click Event ] on external image

```
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path5)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path6)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path7)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path8)
```

Comment: What type of layer? Can you give a little more information on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add a click event for an image, so that when I click an external image it changes the source of the tile layer (L.tilelayer.deepzoom). It would be awesome if I could get it to change the layer source of 4 layers to different paths. 

For Example:


L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path1)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path2)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path3)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path4)

[ Button Click Event ] on external image

L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path5)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path6)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path7)
L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 options for you:

1. Try the [setUrl](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-seturl) method of the tileLayer class. I've never used it myself, but it looks like it might do what you are looking for. From the docs: "Updates the layer's URL template and redraws it."
2. You could also use a layerGroup to hold your tile layers. In the button click event you would clear the existing layers and add new layers. Something like this:

[Initial loading]

```
// I'm assuming you have some data structure with each layer url to load
// I called it myLayers for this example
var layers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
myLayers.forEach(function(path){
    L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path).addTo(layers);
});
```

[Button Click Event]

```
layers.clearLayers();
myLayers.forEach(function(path){
    L.tilelayer.deepzoom(path).addTo(layers);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I could setUrl because it was from the WMS tile layer, but I guess deepzoom is the same thing. Many thanks! :D